# Eliminar en Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy tratando de eliminar un post en Laravel y me sale   `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Así tengo mi boton de eliminar

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <form method="DELETE" action="{{ url('news/news/destroy').'/'. $info->id }}" role="form">  
            {!! Form::submit('Delete this task?', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

MI controlador

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $info = News::find($id);


        $info->delete();

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully deleted!');

        return view('news.index',['info' => $info]);
    }
```

MI ruta

```
Route::delete('news/news/destroy/{id}', 'NewsController@destroy');
```

¿Es el método correcto?

Answer (score 1):

El form va con `POST` y el `DELETE` se pone en un input oculto cuyo nombre debe ser `_method`.

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('news/news/destroy').'/'. $info->id }}" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Delete this task?', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

tambien se puede hacer lo siguiente

```
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('Controller@method',$info->id),'method'=>'delete'))}}
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
{{Form::close()}}
```